# Trying to order character values in a column based on name

Tags: r, dataframe

```
y<-data.frame(householdincome$State,householdincome$Income.Level,householdincome$Percent.of.Total)
factor(y$householdincome.Income.Level,levels = c("$15,000 to $19,999","$20,000 to $24,999","$200,000 or more"))
y[order(y$householdincome.Income.Level),]
```

I need to order the output starting with 200,000 or more, however my data frame output disregards all values of that name and only lists certain values in the column that i am not looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `[order(y$Level,decreasing=TRUE),]`

```
householdincome<-data.frame("State" = c("London", "Reading", "Southampton"), 
                 "Level" = c("$15,000 to $19,999","$20,000 to $24,999","$200,000 or more"),
                 "Percent.of.Total" = c(runif(3, 0, 100)))


y<-data.frame(householdincome)
y$Level<-factor(y$Level)

y[order(y$Level,decreasing=TRUE),]

        State              Level Percent.of.Total
3 Southampton   $200,000 or more         10.37236
2     Reading $20,000 to $24,999         66.84539
1      London $15,000 to $19,999         98.65112
```